# Will "stationary" air sorrounding a hot pipe from a wood stove act as insulation with a given time?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

The inner pipe (colored in red) radiates considerable more heat than the current one so I'm planning on extending the more thermally conductive one so that it heats better.
Will removing the outer pipe provide more heating to the environment?

Consider that the air that gets trapped in between both pipes does not circulate and it will be "stuck" absorbing the heat. Will this air dampen the desired effect of heating my home or with a given time both alternatives would be the same?

[image: Both alternatives to be considered (and only these two)]

Comment: IDK, but don't forget that you have to balance two opposing considerations. Removing more heat from the flue gas will improve the efficiency of your heater, but it will reduce the effectiveness of the chimney (i.e., it will reduce the "draft".)

Comment: Also consider the effect of removing an outer pipe that insulates the hot inner pipe.  The flue gases will cool off more as heat is transferred to the inside of your house.  Will components of the flue gas condense on the inside of the inner pipe and develop into a fire hazard over time?  It would probably be wise to get an answer to this question before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider this:**

It can be shown that the heat loss $q$ (in Watt per unit of length) of a homogeneously insulated cylinder is given by:

$$q=\frac{\pi \Delta T}{\frac{1}{2k}\ln \frac{D}{d}+\frac{1}{hD}}$$

It's worth doing a little function analysis on that formula.

We assume *heat conduction* on $[d,D]$ and *heat convection* from the outer layer at $D$.

[image: Cylinder heat loss]

Where:

- $\Delta T=T_c-T_a=\text{constant}$
- $k\:\text{and}\:h\:\text{are both constants}:$ heat conductivity and heat convection transfer coefficient, resp.
- $d=\text constant$: diameter

Now determine for which value of $D$, in function of $k$ and $h$, **$q$ is minimised**.

Write:

$$q=\frac{\pi \Delta T}{u}$$

Then:

$$\frac{1}{u}$$

Calculate $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}D}=u'$:

$$u'=\frac{1}{2kD}-\frac{1}{hD^2}=\frac{hD^2-2kD}{2khD^3}=\frac{hD-2k}{2khD^2}$$

So that:

$$\frac{\text{d}q}{\text{d}D}=-\frac{\pi \Delta T}{2u^2khD^2} (hD-2k)$$
For an optimum we must have:
$$\frac{\text{d}q}{\text{d}D}=0$$

$$hD-2k=0$$

$$\boxed{D=\frac{2k}{h}}$$

So for this value of $D$ the heat flux $q$ is **minimised**, which is of course the opposite of what you are trying to achieve.

While your own geometry does differ somewhat from the idealised situation above, there are also strong similarities.

Answer (score 0):

yes ideed, it absolutely will. trapped air acts as a good insulator (at least until buoyant forces set it into motion and it starts *convecting*). The easiest way by far to pull more heat out of a flue pipe is to use *single-wall* pipe of the largest possible diameter (i.e., 8") for the run that is inside the living space and direct a fan over it.

Note that this presupposes you know how to operate a wood stove for maximum efficiency, which occurs when the stove is running at its maximum rated output with a slight excess of oxygen in the flue. This minimizes release of unburned hydrocarbons and prevents creosote buildup in the flue.

When a stove is running in this regime, even having two stories' worth of single-wall flue pipe with forced-fan heat exchange will not compromise the flue pipe's ability to maintain a draft, and even 30 years of operation will not result in any appreciable creosote buildup in the pipe.